# how to redirect entire pattern of lines from a file. grep, awk,sed etc.,

Tags: shell, scripting

```
$cat datafile

BlankLine
a Line start with "Cn:"
BlankLine
```

Want to direct these lines to a new file and remove it from current file.
datafile contains plenty of lines.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` may do the job,

```
$ sed -e '/BlankLine/,/BlankLine/w newfile' -i -e '/BlankLine/,/BlankLine/d' datafile
```

Brief explanation,

1. `'/BlankLine/,/BlankLine/w newfile'`: search the lines start from 'BlankLine' to another 'BlankLine', and write them to **newfile**.
2. `-i -e '/BlankLine/,/BlankLine/d'`: delete the lines which were wrote in datafile.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Blank line is actually an empty line.

Comment: So you just need to direct the line `a Line start with "Cn:"` to another file?

Comment: no, there could be more patterns like 
<pre>
BlankLine
a Line start with "Cn:"
a Line start with "Sn:"
BlankLine
</pre>
what I need is, If there is only "Cn" between the balnk lines, I want to move them.